# How to read file from BlobStore by name

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

Suppose I have some uploading form for files like the one in documentation
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/

If I saved file `file.txt` to the blobstore, how can I get it from it if I dont know it's `BlobKey`. More precisely, I want to get this file with a request like this: `myapp.appspot.com/getfile?file_name=file.txt` and I just want to see file `file.txt` on this url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Blobstore, you have to remember a key somewhere in order to retrieve the blob.

If you use Blobstore to store files in Cloud Storage, then you can access them using an object name,which can be an original name of an uploaded file.

If your file is public, you can access it directly:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/" + bucket + "/" + objectName
```

If you want to read it first in your app, and then return to a client, then you can use:

```
String filename = "/gs/" + bucket + "/" + objectName;
BlobstoreService blobService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
blobService.serve(blobService.createGsBlobKey(filename), response);
```

Comment: what `bucket` means here and how cat I know if my file is public? I just upload it using `<form action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload") %>" method="post">"` and I do almost nothing in `UploadServlet` which maps to `/upload`

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were using BlobstoreService to store objects in Google Cloud Storage. I will update my answer.

Comment: I tryed your sollution `https://storage.googleapis.com/" + bucket + "/" + objectName` but seems like file in bucket has different name than the one was when I was uploading it. So do I still have to save it (name in bucket) somewhere for every file?

Comment: It depends on how you upload a file. If you write a file to Cloud Storage from your own servlet, you can specify the file name that you want. But if you use "uploadUrl" to upload the files directly to the Cloud Storage, unfortunately, there is no way to specify the object name - as far as I know.

Comment: but how can I upload some file on server from my servlet without `uploadUrl`? Basically all I want from my server is to upload some file `file.txt` and after that download it by it's name `file.txt`

Comment: Scroll down to "Writing files" https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted